# I want to select different packages on the basis of states, how to get value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

```
public ActionResult Rajasthan()
{
    //List<PackageGallery> all = new List<PackageGallery>();
    using (travelAndTourismEntities objentity = new travelAndTourismEntities())
    {
        List<PackageGallery> all = (from p in objentity.PackageGalleries where p.ParentCategory == "Rajasthan" orderby p.Imageid select p).ToList();

        // all = objentity.PackageGalleries.ToList();
        return View(all);
    }
}
```

I am writing this query but this is specific to rajasthan only how to make it generalize

Comment: you can pass in parameter `public actionresult Rajasthan(string state)` and use `p.ParentCategory == state` instead of `p.ParentCategory == "Rajasthan"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a parameter to your action method where you accept the state name you want to use in your filter.

```
public ActionResult PackageGalleries(string id)
{
    var all = new List<PackageGallery>();
    using (var db = new travelAndTourismEntities())
    {
       all = db.PackageGalleries
                  .Where(s=>s.ParentCategory==id)
                  .OrderBy(x=>x.ImageId).ToList();
    }
    return View(all);
}
```

And you can call it like `yourSiteName/yourControllerName/PackageGalleries/rajasthan` or `yourSiteName/yourControllerName/PackageGalleries/kerala`

The last part of the url will be mapped to the `id` parameter of the action method.